# unable to install meterial ui core on react js project

Tags: npm

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...PcwdrnQaE/odvJa0AKevg'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\badrmohammed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-18T19_21_29_506Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\badrmohammed\Downloads\Compressed\Shipping> npm install @material-ui/core
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...PcwdrnQaE/odvJa0AKevg'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\badrmohammed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-18T19_23_26_758Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

just run 
`npm install @popperjs/core --save` 
and then 
`npm uninstall popper.js --save` 
from within your project directory to install Popper v2 and uninstall the deprecated version. 
then run `npm install @material-ui/core --save`